# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringMVC'

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm getting this error in my SpringMVC project.I have to manually add the full path in browser to run the code but I cann't run it directly.

```
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
            WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/] in DispatcherServlet  with name 'SpringMVC'
```

web.xml:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
            <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
            <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
            </welcome-file-list>
            <servlet>
            <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>
            <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
            </web-app>
```

springMVC-servlet.xml:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

            <context:component-scan base-package="com.adept.springMVC"></context:component-scan>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>

            </bean>

            </beans>
```

StudentControler.java:

```
            package com.adept.springMVC;

            import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
            import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
            import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
            @Controller
            public class StudentControler {
            @RequestMapping(value="/student1",method=RequestMethod.GET)
            public ModelAndView student1(){
            return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student());
            }
            @RequestMapping(value="/addStudent",method=RequestMethod.POST)
            public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("springWeb1")Student stud,ModelMap map){
            map.addAttribute("name",stud.getName());
            map.addAttribute("id", stud.getId());
            map.addAttribute("dept", stud.getDept());
            return "result";
            }
           }
```

student.jsp:

```
            <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
            pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
            <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Spring MVC</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h1>Student Information</h1>
            <form:form method="post" action="/SpringMVC/addStudent">
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td><form:label path="name">Name:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><form:label path="id">Id:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><form:label path="dept">Department:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="dept" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>  
            </form:form>

            </body>
            </html>
```

result.jsp:

```
            <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
            pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
            <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Output</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h1>Student Information</h1>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>${name}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Id:</td>
            <td>${id}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Department:</td>
            <td>${dept}</td>
            </tr>
            </table>  
            </body>
            </html>
```

please tell me how to solve the problem.

Comment: What url you are using to get the page?

Comment: Define "full path" and "run directly".

Comment: http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/student1 ...actually after running the project I get http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/.I have to manually add the student1 after the URL

Comment: I don't want to define the full path manually

Comment: Obviously, since your unique GET-mapped controller method is mapped to `/student1`. If you want something to be on `/`, then you need a controller method mapped to `/`

Comment: can you write that portion??

Comment: Replace `@RequestMapping(value="/student1",method=RequestMethod.GET)` by `@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change springMVC-servlet.xml to capital S SpringMVC-servlet.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think your application context path is “/”, not “SpringMVC” . Your request uri need not "/SpringMVC" ,such as "http://localhost:8080/student1"

Answer (score 0):

change your application **pom.xml**

```
 <properties>
       <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
  </properties>

 <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post your project structure. If web.xml have not been edited Specifically, it cannot run directly in the project. You can only enter the URL in the browser and run the JSP through the following process.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7UUl.png)

Solution：

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31211569)